# Using AppendOnlyHistory in a display template

Tags: display-template

I'm using a content search web part and would like to be able to get an append comments text field displayed.  I want all text, the author, and the timestamp displayed for each item, just like how it is if you were to use it in a data view web part.  Is this possible through a display template?

This is the XSL that I'm referring to that works in a data view web part:
`<SharePoint:AppendOnlyHistory FieldName="Comments" runat="server" ControlMode="Display" ItemId="{@ID}"/>`

Comment: Have you tried the above control ? It should work in a Data View Webpart

Comment: It works in a data view web part fine, but I'm using a content search web part for this.  Can I somehow use this in a display template instead?